# Channel estimation

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, estimation, fading-channel

In single-carrier systems, at the receiver, when we need to do channel estimation and equalization? Do we need to do before timing synchronization and CFO correction or before it? And, please let me how it behaves if it is before synchronization or after synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you do center frequency correction followed by some sort of coarse timing synchronization and then equalization. The equalizer will provide mitigation against ISI and additional timing synchronization.